# How to add axios interceptors in next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, next.js

I have a fresh next.js project and I want to use axios interceptors in order to do some auth with JWT Tokens. Issue is im not sure where to add the below code from the axios docs

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
console.log(config)
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

simply importing it into _app.tsx did not work.

Comment: How are you using axios in your project, did you create an [instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) of axios, or default [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api)?